# URL Scheme not working from native iOS app

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I have a custom defined URL scheme and a TARGET app that registered this scheme to be recognized.

When I launch a WEB app in mobile Safari and I push a button in the WEB App, there is an URL link provided by the button, and a dedicated TARGET application is launched - which is the desired behaviour.

However if I launch a native SOURCE app, and implement an action on a UIButton, and there I call the appdelegate to openURL and pass the same url that is used from the web app, TARGET app is not launched. 
The [UIApplication canOpenURL] check even returns NO, which is strange, since TARGET App DID register that custom URL Scheme correctly, otherwise it would not work from the web app.

Any help?

PS:SOURCE and TARGET are just convenient names for SO.

UPDATE:

```
- (IBAction)handleAction:(id)sender
{
    NSString *urlString = @"nda://nda.undernda/actionundernda?someparamters..";

BOOL isURLSchemeRegistered = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

if (isURLSchemeRegistered == YES)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:urlString]];
    }
else
  {
    //go to appstore
  }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough info to answer your question. Please supply the scheme you're using as well as code examples and screenshot of scheme settings?

Comment: Update your question with the actual code you use to call `openURL:`.

Comment: please provide us the code so we can see what you're talking about!

Comment: I added the code.This method is ridiculously trivial..And I can't disclose the url content, I am under NDA..so I am not sure how it can help...

Comment: 1) Drop the `== YES` part of the `if` statement. Never explicitly compare a `BOOL` against `YES` or `NO`. Simply do `if (someBool)` or `if (!someBool)`. 2) At the time the posted code is called, there actually is another app installed that registers the `nda` URL scheme? 3) Verify there is no typo in the actual URL scheme you have.

Comment: Are you returning YES for `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`

Comment: @BooRanger I return YES in the delegate call in the target app. As I said, it launches with no issue, if triggered from mobile safari.
Rmaddy That is not the real URL, i cannot show it, as I said I am under NDA. But the url works just fine if I use it from mobile web app. I did not retype it by hand or anything.

Comment: As an additional check, I copied the url ***directly from the method*** to mac clipboard and pasted into mobile safari in my ios simulator. Target app launched without problems. That proves url is ok.

Comment: I can't see or think of any reason why it wouldn't work, is it an extension and you just don't want to mention it because only today widget are allowed open urls. If safari works you could do a awful workaround (just awful) and open the url in a hidden UIWebView.

Comment: Stupid questions time: (1) is the URL scheme complicated enough to have a possible typo in the native code that would cause it to fail there but not in your canned webpage? (2) What version of iOS and have you checked the plist entries for scheme support to make sure there's nothing odd there? I can't think of anything that would qualify, but since you're down to the fact that the app-level scheme handling doesn't seem to be being recognized, there may be some config subtlety going on that is _almost_ correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok ,so the problem was that he url had characters that were not escaped using UTF8 encoding.

Solution:

```
    NSString *urlString = @"sorry..can't show this :(";
NSString *escapedUrlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url =[ NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```